# Preserving Fragment state when navigating back

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, fragmenttransaction

My (reading) app consists of one (MainActivity) and a couple of other fragments.

I have a `LibraryFragment` that lists all saved articles
and a `ReadingFragment` (that is used for reading articles)

An article can contain links, when the users clicks a link I'm using a fragment `.replace` transaction to show a new instance of the `ReadingFragment` , now when I click the back button, my current fragment is removed and the old one is shown, it uses it's arguments to load the content once more (but I lose the scroll position)

I have tried using the `.add` transaction , but for some reason the added fragment overlays the previous one.

My code:

```
  public void showFragment(Fragment fragment, Boolean addToBackStack)
  {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        if (addToBackStack && get_currentFragment() != null) transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
  }
```

I want to preserve the layout and the state of the fragment adding a new instance each time the user clicks a link and immediately restoring the fragment when the user navigates back. (Just like I would do if I were using startActivity)

**Update**

I'm loading the content in the fragment's `onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)` callback

Comment: This is probably related to how you're loading the content.  Can you post that code?

Comment: That content loading is probably where the problem is.  `onActivityCreated` is called both on initial creation and when coming back to the fragment and doing something there (like setting a new list adapter) can easily reset the view state.  Try moving your loading to `onAttach` or `onCreate` and see if that resolves things.

Comment: @blahdiblah but if I use onCreate the ui is not ready , because (onCreateView is executed after onCreate)

Comment: FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);transaction.addToBackStack("name");
        transaction.commit();